# Problems with testing create method in Spock

Tags: spring-boot, testing, groovy, spock

> Hey guys, I am new in spock and i have problems with writing tests for save method and setDefaultFormFieldConfig(). Could You help me? i don't know what is wrong with my test.

```
public ForConfig create(ForConfig forConfig, Long id) {
    setNormal(forConfig, "title", "offer.label.title", FieldType.IN);
    setNormal(forConfig, "shortDescription", "offer.label.shortDescription", FieldType.TEXTAREA);
    forConfig.setCategory(categService.findById(id));
    return forConRep.save(formConfig);
}



 private void setNormal(FormConfig forConfig, String n, String s, FieldType fieldType) {
        if (formConfig.getFc().stream()
                .noneMatch(fieldConfig -> fieldConfig.getName().equals(name))) {
            forConfig.getFieldsConfig()
                    .add(new FieldConfig(n, s, null, "M",
                            fieldType, false, false, true, null));
        }
```

> *Test for save method:*

```
def 'test create forConfig without normal fields'() {
    given:
    def forConfig = Mock(FormConfig)
    forConfig.getFieldsConfig() >> new ArrayList<Config>()
    def forConfRep = Mock(ForConRep);
    def categService = Mock(CategService);
    def impl = new ForConfServiceImpl(forConfRep, categService)
    forConfRep.save(_) >> new FormConfig()
    categoryService.findById(_) >> new Categ()

    when:
    impl.create(forConfig, 1)

    then:
    1 * forConfig.getFieldsConfig().add(_)
    2 * forConfig.setCategory(_)
}
```

> And in the console I get these errors:

```
Too few invocations for:

1 * formConfig.getFieldsConfig().add(_)   (0 invocations)

Unmatched invocations (ordered by similarity):

None

Too few invocations for:

2 * formConfig.setCategory(_)   (1 invocation)

Unmatched invocations (ordered by similarity):

None



    at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.InteractionScope.verifyInteractions(InteractionScope.java:98)
    at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.MockController.leaveScope(MockController.java:77)
    at pl.offer.service.impl.ForConfServiceImplSpec.test save formConfig without defaults fields(FormConfigServiceImplSpec.groovy:24)


Process finished with exit code -1
```

> Could You help me?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Thanks for the interesting question. Please be advised to learn what an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is and why it is so tremendously helpful in order to get qualified help here: simply because it makes your problem reproducible. From just reading your fairly complex code with many dependencies (classes and objects used) it is very difficult to find the root cause of your problem. I had to create lots of helper classes in order to even make application and test classes compile, see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two major problems in your test:

1. The counts are wrong, you got them reversed in your `then:` block:

   - The `add(..)` method should be called twice because `setDefaultFormFieldConfig(..)` is also called twice.
   - The `setCategory(..)` method should only be called once.
2. If you are trying to verify an interaction on `add(..)` which is a `List` method, you have to inject a mock object for it. For simplicity's sake and in order to avoid having to stub lots of `List` methods, I recommend to just use a `Spy` object. What you cannot do, though, is write it as a call chain like `1 * formConfig.getFieldsConfig().add(_)`, you have to directly verify the target mock/spy, e.g. `2 * fieldConfigList.add(_)`.

Here is an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

**Dummy dependency classes to make application and test compile and run:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q65144983;

public class Category {
  private String name;

  public Category() { }

  public Category(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q65144983;

public class CategoryService {
  public Category findById(Long categoryId) {
    return new Category("BY_ID_" + categoryId);
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q65144983;

public class FieldConfig {
  private String name;

  public FieldConfig(String name, String label, Object o, String match, FieldType type, boolean b, boolean b1, boolean b2, Object o1) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q65144983;

public enum FieldType {
  TEXTAREA, INPUT
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q65144983;

import java.util.List;

public class FormConfig {
  private Category category;
  private List<FieldConfig> fieldsConfig;

  public FormConfig() {}

  public void setCategory(Category category) {
    this.category = category;
  }

  public List<FieldConfig> getFieldsConfig() {
    return fieldsConfig;
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q65144983;

public class FormConfigRepository {
  public FormConfig save(FormConfig formConfig) {
    return formConfig;
  }
}
```

**The interface + implementation under test:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q65144983;

public interface FormConfigService {
  FormConfig save(FormConfig formConfig, Long categoryId);
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q65144983;

public class FormConfigServiceImpl implements FormConfigService {
  private FormConfigRepository formConfigRepository;
  private CategoryService categoryService;

  public FormConfigServiceImpl(FormConfigRepository formConfigRepository, CategoryService categoryService) {
    this.formConfigRepository = formConfigRepository;
    this.categoryService = categoryService;
  }

  @Override
  public FormConfig save(FormConfig formConfig, Long categoryId) {
    setDefaultFormFieldConfig(formConfig, "title", "offer.label.title", FieldType.INPUT);
    setDefaultFormFieldConfig(formConfig, "shortDescription", "offer.label.shortDescription", FieldType.TEXTAREA);
    formConfig.setCategory(categoryService.findById(categoryId));
    return formConfigRepository.save(formConfig);
  }

  private void setDefaultFormFieldConfig(FormConfig formConfig, String name, String label, FieldType type) {
    if (
      formConfig.getFieldsConfig().stream()
        .noneMatch(fieldConfig -> fieldConfig.getName().equals(name))
    )
    {
      formConfig.getFieldsConfig()
        .add(new FieldConfig(name, label, null, "MATCH", type, false, false, true, null));
    }
  }
}
```

**Spock test:**

I hope you are okay with me making the mocks more type-safe and stubbing methods inline. Otherwise, the test is pretty much the same as yours. I only fixed the two problems mentioned at the beginning.

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q65144983

import spock.lang.Specification

class FormConfigServiceImplTest extends Specification {
  def 'test save formConfig without defaults fields'() {
    given:
    List fieldConfigList = Spy(new ArrayList<FieldConfig>())
    FormConfig formConfig = Mock() {
      getFieldsConfig() >> fieldConfigList
    }
    FormConfigRepository formConfigRepository = Mock() {
      save(_) >> new FormConfig()
    }
    CategoryService categoryService = Mock() {
      findById(_) >> new Category()
    }
    def formConfigService = new FormConfigServiceImpl(formConfigRepository, categoryService)

    when:
    formConfigService.save(formConfig, 1)

    then:
    2 * fieldConfigList.add(_)
    1 * formConfig.setCategory(_)
  }
}
```

P.S.: I showed you how to technically solve your problem with Spock. I do believe though, that this way of testing the internals of an implementation might not be the right way of testing your application. These kinds of tests tend to be brittle and break easily if you do some internal refactoring. You will have to refactor your tests too, which is fine in general. But I recommend you to focus on testing the public API of your application, not obsess about the internal workings, unless they are absolutely vital. Then of course you can and maybe should test them.